# What is the easiest way to add a string on the beginning of every line of the file from the command line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I am looking for a way to add some string to the beginning of every line (same string for every line).
Not something customizable but rather something that will be easy to remember and available on every POSIX-compliant platform (and every shell as well).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^/your_string /' your_file
```

Thanks to Stephane and Marco's comments, note that the `-i` option isn't POSIX. A POSIX way to do the above would be

```
sed 's/^/your_string /' your_file > tmp_copy && mv tmp_copy your_file
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/your_string /' your_file
```

**Explanation**

Both commands perform a regex substitution, replacing the beginning of a line (`^`) with your desired string. The `-i` switch in both commands makes sure the file is edited in place (i.e. the changes are reflected in the file instead of printed to stdout).

`sed` should be available on any POSIX-compliant OS and `perl` should be available on most modern Unices except perhaps for the ones that [have gone through the effort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48019/26909) of removing it.

Comment: Small correction: The `-i` switch does not edit the file in place. It creates a new file and overwrites the original one after it's done (proof: the inode changes). There are not many tools which actually do in-place editing, which is a dangerous operation. Furthermore, since you mention POSIX, the `-i` switch is not mandatory for a POSIX compatible `sed`, it's a feature of some particular implementations.

Comment: `sed -i` is not POSIX. It's GNU. FreeBSD `sed` has a similar option, but you need `sed -i ''` there.

Comment: @Marco I'm aware that `-i` creates a temporary copy (that's why I said the changes are _reflected_ in the original file); I meant that you get the same semantics as in-place substitution. Please check that the updated answer is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the changes are reflected in a new file with the same name as the original.

Comment: I often use `$$` (the current shell's process id) as part of a temporary file name; it avoids the effort of thinking of a guaranteed unique name every time: `command filename > filename.$$ && mv filename.$$ filename`

Answer (score 14):

```
:|paste -d'foo ' - - - - input > output
```

(just kidding, though you'll probably find it's the fastest of all the solutions posted here :-b).

The canonical way is:

```
sed 's/^/foo /' < input > output
```

However, it's not easily adapted to arbitrary strings. For instance,

```
sed "s/^/$var /"
```

Only works if `$var` doesn't contain, `&`, `\`, `/` nor newline characters, and is an arbitrary command execution vulnerability in GNU sed at least if that cannot be guaranteed.

In that regard,

```
export var
awk '{print ENVIRON["var"], $0}'
```

or

```
perl -pe '$_="$ENV{var} $_"'
```

would work better.

Comment: that's something interesting... :P

Answer (score 5):

I present a solution using `awk` prepending the string “foo”.

```
awk '{ print "foo", $0; }' input > output
```

`awk` is cross-platform and available on any POSIX system. It does not do in-place editing. If you want to edit a file without creating a second one, you will have to use a temporary file. See Joseph's `sed` answer, it shows the syntax. Another hack is to use the following syntax, which is basically creating a temporary file with the same file name as the original file.

```
{ rm file; awk '{ print "foo", $0 }' > file; } < file
```

Comment: `reducto# wc -l foo`
`     914 foo`
`reducto# { rm foo ; awk '{ print "prepend" , $0 }' > foo } < foo`
`>`
This doesn't seem to work.  I was trying because the redirecting to original made me nervous, but it won't even start.

Comment: This example will work if it uses parentheses for the outside rather than curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the problems of in-place editing with the stream tools by using a tool that normally does in-place editing - an editor!

```
ex sample.txt -c "%s/^/foo /" -c wq
```

There is an additional advantage that the commands are easy and obvious to anyone who is versed in the one true editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl` to do this:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/^/mystring /' afile.txt
```

#### Example

Create a sample file.

```
$ seq 5 > afile.txt

$ cat afile.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```

Run the above command:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/^/mystring /' afile.txt

$ cat afile.txt
mystring 1
mystring 2
mystring 3
mystring 4
mystring 5
```

Comment: Perl seems to be universal nowadays, but for a long time it wasn't.  And I'm betting there are a couple rare UNIX variants out there that steadfastly refuse to have perl as part of the base.  Something to be aware of.

Comment: @kurtm see the discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11307976#11307976). Apparently, AIX does not have Perl by default and nor do embedded systems.

Comment: @terdon Yeah.  I suspected AIX wouldn't, but I haven't really worked with AIX, so couldn't say for sure.  And yeah, perl is a bit bloated for embedded systems.  That's why I put the warning on there.  I remember the days when perl was only ever an add-on...

Comment: Perl is not at all universal.  It's popular in Linux distributions to include it in the base, but that's about it.

Comment: @DavidSainty The BSDs also seem to include it and I'm fairly certain Solaris does too (I'm not touching Solaris any more, so I'm not checking).  But that's why I said "seems".

Comment: @DavidSainty - it's universal enough. The Q was tagged with Bash so I find it extremely hard to imagine a system that has Bash but not Perl. At any rate, here's one of 5 answers, several of the others show how to use `sed`, I showed how to use Perl....not looking for a holy war on the matter.

Comment: @kurtm which BSDs have Perl in the base distribution?

Comment: @DavidSainty Apparently only OpenBSD.  I guess I made the assumption since the Open folks tend to be conservative about what they allow in base.  OpenBSD definitively does have it in base.

Comment: @slm: "*I find it extremely hard to imagine a system that has Bash but not Perl*". I have several such systems sitting on my desk. (They happen to be embedded systems.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - What version of Bash, and not some stripped down version that's part of Busybox?

Comment: @sim: It's bash 3.1.17, at least on the one I'm logged into at the moment.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Yeah this is a pretty ancient system, it's almost a 10 year old release, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html. Shall I qualify my statement that I can't imagine a system with a release of Bash in the last 5 years 8-).

Comment: @slm - i don't think there were too many *embedded systems* - at least not the kind you'd keep on your desk - capable of running a `bash` - v3 or otherwise - 5 or 6 years ago. However, there are many systems - even built today - which have a `bash` v3 installed by default *(like Mac OSX)*, because later releases are GPL v3 which is *very* unfriendly to to commercialization - especially of the embedded variety - of any kind *(some people say GPL v3 woldn't have happened at all were it not for TiVo)*. And so I doubt Keith's devs were so ancient as all that.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply using Bash**

```
 while IFS= read -r line; do echo "foo" "${line}" ; done  < input > Output
```

**Using Python**

```
python -c "import sys; print 'foo '.join([ l for l in sys.stdin.readlines() ])" < input > Output
```

If you want to edit in-place

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(['inputfile'], inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write('foo {l}'.format(l=line))
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633485/insert-string-at-the-beginning-of-each-line)

Comment: Why it's working faster than awk ?

Comment: It's only going to work faster than `awk` on very small files. The behavior varies across echo implementations and it strips leading and trailing blanks and processes backslashes specially.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes. you are 100% correct just tested... http://paste.ubuntu.com/6210934/

Comment: `prefix () { while IFS= read -r REPLY; do printf "%s%s\n" "$1" "$REPLY"; done; }` ought to be more correct.

Comment: Why the `{}`? I think @Matt was suggesting you make it into a named function, what's the point of `{}` without a function name?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do the following:

```
vi filename.txt
```

<kbd>Esc</kbd> (to make sure you're in `NORMAL` mode), and then enter the following command:

```
:1,$ s/^/mystring
```

Comment: Note that since the user is asking about every line of the file, you could replace `1,$ ` with simply `%`. This makes the command `:%s/^/string/`.